# Using PHP sessions for PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: php, paypal, session-variables

PHP sessions live until the user leaves the page. So when he clicks on a PayPal Express Checkout button he's redirected to PayPal's website to pay there and then he's redirected back to the site. But then the session (and all info related to the purchase/order) is gone !

Does it mean that cookies rather than sessions must be used with PayPal Express Checkout ?

Comment: No. PHP sessions live until the user closes the browser. There is no fool-proof reliable method to tell PHP when a user leaves a page.

Comment: The session should live as long as the browser instance that started the session has not been closed. That is due to the way that the session cookie is created by PHP. For example, I can start a session, open a new tab, close the current tab, then redirect the newly opened tab to my site, and the session will live.

Comment: Oops you're right guys, my mistake.